# Will the normal Visual Studio 2013 .exe work if installing from a flash drive?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, exe, usb-flash-drive

I can't download the .ISO, as it's going to take me 9 hours. I'm wanting to take the setup .exe and put that on a flash drive, and then install it on my PC at my other house where I haven't had internet installed yet. Thanks, very much everyone here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose **no** as setup.exe requires all files that are included in .iso. If setup.exe is the file which you download from the Microsoft site, it will only start web installation and will try to download all required files.